# Do Cauchy Riemann conditions lead to saddle points everywhere in the domain?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm starting to learn about complex differentiability. I understand that given a complex function $f = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, the Cauchy Riemann equations lead to the condition that $\partial^2u/\partial x^2 = -\partial^2u/\partial y^2$ at every point where the function is differentiable.

Now, this is the condition that is also satisfied by a saddle $x^2 - y^2$, or a generic saddle like figure: $x^{2n} - y^{2n}$.

Given a complex function that is differentiable everywhere over a continuous domain, obviously the condition should also be satisfied for every point in the domain. But the condition means that the point (for which the condition is met) is actually a saddle point. What I don't get is: how can **every** point in a domain be a saddle point? What would such a surface look like? I don't understand how every point and all its infinitestimally adjacent points (in said domain) all be saddles - if a point is a saddle, its adjacent points cannot be saddles as well. So, how does this fit in with the function being differentiable over the entire domain?

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I seem to have confused myself nicely. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: The Cauchy Riemann equations mean that as $z \to z_0$ : $f(z) = f(z_0)+ C (z-z_0)+o(|z-z_0|)$ where $C = f'(z_0)$ doesn't depend on the path $z \to z_0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit upon what you mean by a saddle point?

A critial point for $u$  is a point for which $\partial_x u=\partial_y u = 0$.
By C-R this also means that  $\partial_x v=\partial_y v = 0$. So real and imaginary part have simultaneous critical points.

Normally (at least what I am used to) one only associates a saddle point with a critical point. But in that case indeed it has to be a saddle point. A way to see this in terms of differential geometry is to note that the Hessian $H_u(x,y)$ (the 2nd derivative of $u$) has
zero trace $${\rm tr} (H) = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + 
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0, $$ so that the two (real) eigenvalues have opposite signs. Another interpretation is in terms of the max principle for harmonic functions: No harmonic function can have a local max unless being constant (on a connected domain).

Comment: Thanks. By saddle, I simply meant something which visually looks like a saddle, i.e. where the 2nd partial derivatives are of opposite sign. What I was trying to say was: if a point is a saddle point, its adjacent points cannot be saddles as well. So, how does this fit in with the function being differentiable over the entire domain - i.e. every point in the domain being a saddle?  (I have now updated the question with this text)

Comment: I think it comes back to a more precise definition of saddle point. To you does the function $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ have a saddle point at every point in the plane?

Comment: Yeah, i get it now. you're right. I was misled by my over-reliance on the visual/eyeballing approach. That does have a saddle everywhere. It just doesn't  (at first) look like every point is a saddle when you make a pretty picture. Thank you.